# Angular: how to make field required and trim it?

Tags: angularjs

When I set the `<input ng-model="o.str" required>`, it will pop up a hint "the field is required", without checking for spaces.
How do I make it check it not as `o.str==""`, but `o.str.trim()==""`?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Angular are you on. I see Angular now has `ng-trim`, which by default trims spaces.

See the documentation https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input

Most probably,it is using a angular parser to trim spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'ng-required="true"'

Something like that:

```
    <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="contact.name" placeholder="Name" ng-required="true" ng-minlength="10"/>
```

And for trim strings, you can use ng-trim or ng-trim="true".

Answer (score -1):

I always add a hidden button for the actual submit. The submit button shown just validates the data, then triggers the real submit like this (although in angular it would be ng-click rather than onclick):

```js
function validate() {
    var valid = true;
    $.each($('input'), function(){
        valid = valid && $(this).val().length > 0;
    })
    if (valid) {
        $('#realSubmit').click();
    } else {
        alert('Please fill out all fields!');
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="next2.php" method="post" name="next2" id="next2" onsubmit="return submit();">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" />
    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" />
    <button type="button" onclick="validate()">Submit</button>
    <button type="submit" id="realSubmit" style="display:none"></button>
</form>
```